# What is accent of VJ (brunette woman) in Pacific Heat

Tags: character, pacific-heat

A new Netflix animated series *Pacific Heat* is based in Australia. I am American, and all the accents seem uniform to me except the one used by the brunette female agent named Veronica nickname V.J.

Here is the official "Meet VJ” clip:

Her accent is unfamiliar to me, and to my ears it is very distinct. I watch lots of English TV shows like *Midsomer Murders* and *That Mitchell and Webb Look* so I'm familiar with those accents. I've seen *Deathgasm* and *Black Sheep* which are New Zealand comedy horror movies. I've watched Irish movies like *The Wind That Shakes the Barley* and *Breakfast on Pluto*. I used to work with a Scotsman whom I could barely understand, and I also have similar trouble understanding her, but that doesn't mean they're the same.

I've never heard her particular accent before. I'm guessing it is an obscure accent that is localized to some social subculture.

Can anyone tell me what her accent is?

Note that I don't think the actress accent is the same as the character accent.

My own guesses are:

1. redneck New Zealand
2. a French woman who learned English in Australia?
3. Actress mocking an Australian accent?

Comment: The accent of the woman that says *"You can get your hand off my arse"* at around 55 seconds in on [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kgLo8vudXg) is British.

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you include the name of the agent in your question.  Is it Veronica Delane, played by Lucia Mastrantone?

Comment: @BrettFromLA I don't think the character accent is the same as the actress. It must be an affected accent. It's too odd not to be. In any case, next time I watch I will figure out if she is VJ or Maddie

Comment: @AndrewThompson I viewed the clip. VJ speaks a total of 3 words at the start of the scene with the corpse and coffee. This is 2 scenes after the scene you mention.

Comment: Perhaps you should search Youtube and find a clip in which VJ speaks more words. That was just the first one I clicked on. It would be most helpful for people who don't watch the show (e.g. me - though if I had Netflix, I probably would - it seems a hoot) to have more of the speech to work with.

Comment: He said brunette. I agree. Her accent is very weird. Sounds like she is special needs australian. Only an australian can answer this I think. I am also American so I have no idea.

Comment: OMG.... Black Sheep is one of my favorite movies.....

Comment: Thank Goodness Netflix has published a "Meet VJ" clip. No more misdirection.

Answer (score 3):

I at first assumed her accent was South African. However by episode 8 I believe that it is "ethnic Westie" (Western Sydney - from an Italian or Greek background)

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: As one of those 'Ethnic Westies' I concur.

Answer (score 1):

Her accent is definitely ethnic western sydney ( of italian/ greek/ lebanese origin) and could well be based on Effie (as played by Mary Coustas) from the classic Australian comedy series 'acropolis now'.

Answer (score 0):

The actress is from Italy. I assumed it was an Italian attempting to speak with an Australian accent.

Comment: I looked up the actress and can't find out her national of origin although she currently lives in Australia. Do you have reference to her birth place?

Answer (score -1):

V.J. from *Pacific Heat* is South African  for sure!

Here are two videos of young women with South African accents:

Comment: Could people add some more details ?

Comment: So I reviewed the 2 videos above, and I gotta say that I think I can hear the similarities.

Answer (score -2):

She sounds exactly like the girl from Die Antwoord, who is South African.

Comment: But it _isn't_.

Comment: Also, `the girl from Die Antwoord` is known as [Yolandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yolandi_Visser), or better known as the 'Rich Bitch', you'd better respect 'mommy' or you'll get ninja'd!